# How do I log syslog to virtual console from systemd?

Tags: logging, syslog, virtual-console

This fails:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty8.service.d/override.conf 
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/syslog


Aug  2 11:28:22 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:18 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:15 darts02 tail[317]: rts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:27:25 da
Aug  2 11:28:22 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:18 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:15 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:12 darts02 tail[317]: rts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:27:25 da
Aug  2 11:28:22 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:18 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:15 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:12 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:10 darts02 tail[317]: rts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:27:24 da
Aug  2 11:28:22 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:18 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:15 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:12 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:10 darts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:28:08 darts02 tail[317]: rts02 tail[317]: Aug  2 11:27:24 da
```

Cannot find anything on the web...

Answer (score 0):

I partly solved my problem using the APT Package apt://console-log:

```
# /etc/console-log.conf -- configuration file for console-log.
# see console-log.conf(5) for details

# works
tty 9
file /var/log/syslog
group adm # needed in debian

# doesn't work as Xorg.log does not exist yet.
tty 8
file /var/log/Xorg.0.log
less_opts "--LONG-PROMPT --chop-long-lines --jump-target=10 --max-forw-scroll=100 --window=-4 --follow-name"
```

But the less option `--follow-name` doesn't work as explained here: 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/console-log.conf.5.html

No error message in syslog.